# How do I upgrade a pipenv package and ignore prerelease packages?

Tags: pipenv

This fails ("Warning: Your dependencies could not be resolved. You likely have a mismatch in your sub-dependencies.")

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
pipenv install requests
pipenv install black --dev
pipenv update requests
```

The update fails because [black *only* has pre-release versions](https://pypi.org/project/black/#history).

```
# fails with warning
pipenv update requests --pre

# no such option for *update*
pipenv update requests --skip-lock
```

This implies that I'd have to uninstall black, then update the relevant package, then re-install black, for every attempt to update.

So far, all I've found is maybe telling pip to let all updates take the most recent pre-release packages, in this case for black *and* requests. This doesn't seem like a good idea when only black is a permanent pre-release package.

Also, note that pipenv in this case holding up everything because of --dev dependencies that won't matter in the final build.

Answer (score 4):

Try installing a specific version of black.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
pipenv install requests
pipenv install black==18.9b0 # the latest as of 2018-12-09
pipenv update requests
pipenv update requests --pre
# afik, the --pre flag here doesn't do anything
cat Pipfile | grep allow_preleases
# avoids allowing prereleases for all packages
```